# CKEditor 5: Paste plain text

Tags: ckeditor5

I'm testing the new CKEditor: https://craftcms.com/blog/ckeditor-revamped

One of my very first check is "copy & paste" into the RTE, because my editors WILL do this. (I know my editors ...)
And after pasting some words, this is the resulting source code:

```
<p>
    <span style="background-color:rgb(251,252,254);color:rgb(63,77,90);">normaler Text</span>
</p>
```

Unfortunally, this is a blocker for me to use this plugin, because within a very short time, I'll see a lot of formatted (= dirty) text in my projects. And if so, it's very hard to clean the database (rte fields).

I've done some research:
This seems to be a solution https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/pasting/paste-plain-text.html

> To add this feature to your rich-text editor, install the @ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard package.

This is the config of the CKEditor in Craft: https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor/blob/main/package.json
-> @ckeditor/ckeditor5-clipboard is not installed

Do you have an idea or hint, how to solve my problem?

### Edit 2024-03-22

Just tried a copy&paste on the CKEditor demo website (see link above):
It fails -> the unwanted stylings are still in the code.

How do you deal with the consequences of unwanted styles when copy&paste text into CKEditor?

I'm asking, because I'm wandering that I'm not the only one to have this issue???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this again and I could not reproduce my problem / topic -> close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you have an idea or hint, how to solve my problem?

Create an issue describing the problem at https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor/issues and hope that it is updated, or even better, create a pull request with your proposed changes.

If neither results in the change you want, fork it, change it, and install your forked version instead. It's open source and GPL licensed, so you are free to chnage it however you want!