# Redactor RTE -> what about Craft 5?

Tags: plugins, redactor, richtext, craft5

https://plugins.craftcms.com/redactor

Redactor is still not available for Craft 5?
If so, that's a major problem for my upgrade path to Craft 5.

I know the CKEditor plugin, but that's not an option for me:
See my other post: [CKEditor 5: Paste plain text](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/41560/ckeditor-5-paste-plain-text)

Has anyone further information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Redactor has Craft 5 compatibility now (abandoned).

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** Redactor 4.0 has been [tagged](https://github.com/craftcms/redactor/releases/tag/4.0.0), adding Craft 5 compatibility. It can be installed by changing your dependency on `craftcms/redactor` in `composer.json` to

```json
"craftcms/redactor": "^4.0"
```

...and then run `composer update`.

Worth mentioning that Redactor is still on life support though, and the general recommendation is to migrate to [CKEditor](https://plugins.craftcms.com/ckeditor?craft5).

================

*Original answer:*

Pixel & Tonic has previously stated that the Redactor plugin is on life support, but that it will be available for Craft 5. As of March 2024, AFAIK that hasn't changed.

There's no beta release available for the Craft 5-compatible version of Redactor yet, but there is a version in development that can be installed by changing your `craftcms/redactor` dependency in `composer.json` to this:

```json
"craftcms/redactor": "4.0.x-dev"
```

*I have no idea about the state of the development version and it might be safer to wait for a beta or stable release, though.*

Comment: sounds good ... THX!